# How can we check booking dates are in season time from multiple seasons?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have project in laravel for booking rooms. I have a calendar to select dates. I need to check booking dates are in summer or winter season. if not in season, show a message "Sorry not a season time"

I had tried some code. This code will works if there is only one entry in table.  Please check the details given below and help me. Thanks.

**season (table)**

```
id  summer  summer_open  summer_close winter winter_open winter_close hotel

1    2018   2018-05-01   2018-09-20   2017   2017-11-01  2018-04-20    1
2    2019   2019-05-01   2019-09-20   2018   2018-11-01  2019-04-20    1
3    2018   2018-05-01   2018-09-20   2017   2017-11-01  2018-04-20    2
4    2019   2019-05-01   2019-09-20   2018   2018-11-01  2019-04-20    2
```

**Code**

```
<?php

protected function generateDates($now, $end){
  $period = new DatePeriod(
       new DateTime($now),
       new DateInterval('P1D'),
       new DateTime($end)
  );

  return $period;
}

public function checkAvailability(Request $request){
$dateBegin            = $request->dateFrom //2019-09-17;
$dateEnd              = $request->dateTo //2019-09-22;

/* generating dates b/w two dates */
$generateBookingDates = $this->generateDates($dateBegin, $dateEnd); 

/* selecting seasons */
$seasons              = Season::where('hotel', $request->hotelId)->get();

foreach ($generateBookingDates as $key => $generateBookingDate) {
  $generateBookingDat = $generateBookingDate->format('Y-m-d'); //2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21 

  /* Checking season begin */
  foreach($seasons as $season) {

   if(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->summer_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->summer_close)->format('Y-m-d')))
   {
     print_r($generateBookingDat. ' booked on summer season ');
   }
   elseif(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->winter_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->winter_close)->format('Y-m-d'))) 
   {
     print_r($generateBookingDat. ' booked on winter season ');
   }
   else {
       print_r($generateBookingDat. ' Sorry not a season time ');
   }

  }
  /* Checking season end*/

} 

}

?>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you run into, when there is more than one entry in the table?

Comment: @Geshode, If there is more than one entry, everytime I am getting `Sorry not a season time`.

Comment: you are out of season obviously

Comment: I think you need to improve your database structure @samsam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have multiple seasons depending on year, you have to break the loop when a booking date is valid :

```
foreach ($generateBookingDates as $key => $generateBookingDate) {
    $generateBookingDat = $generateBookingDate->format('Y-m-d'); //2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21 

    $bookingDateSeason     = null;
    $bookingDateSeasonType = null;

    /* Checking season begin */
    foreach($seasons as $season) {
        if(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->summer_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->summer_close)->format('Y-m-d')))
        {
            $bookingDateSeasonType = 'summer';
            $bookingDateSeason     = $season;
            /* Stop the loop here at the first valid season */
            break;
        } 
        elseif(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->winter_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->winter_close)->format('Y-m-d'))) 
        {
            $bookingDateSeasonType = 'winter';
            $bookingDateSeason     = $season;
            /* Stop the loop here at the first valid season */
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($bookingDateSeason && $bookingDateSeasonType) 
    {
        print_r($generateBookingDat . ' booked on ' . $bookingDateSeasonType . ' season ' . $bookingDateSeason->{$bookingDateSeasonType});
    } 
    else 
    {
        print_r($generateBookingDat . ' Sorry not a season time ');

    }
}

// 2019-09-17 booked on summer season 2019
// 2019-09-18 booked on summer season 2019
// 2019-09-19 booked on summer season 2019
// 2019-09-20 Sorry not a season time
// 2019-09-21 Sorry not a season time
```

This code should do the trick, but in my opinion, you should first retrive the season based on the year of the booking date. In this way you can avoid to loop in multiple seasons.

```
/* generating dates b/w two dates */
$generateBookingDates = $this->generateDates($dateBegin, $dateEnd); 

/* selecting seasons */
//$seasons              = Season::where('hotel', $request->hotelId)->get(); <--- Don't need this line anymore

foreach ($generateBookingDates as $key => $generateBookingDate) {
    $generateBookingDat = $generateBookingDate->format('Y-m-d'); //2019-09-17, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19, 2019-09-20, 2019-09-21 

    $bookingYear = $generateBookingDate->format('Y');
    $season      = /* Season::where('hotel', $request->hotelId)->get(); ... and where year = $bookingYear */

    if(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->summer_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->summer_close)->format('Y-m-d')))
    {
        print_r($generateBookingDat. ' booked on summer season ');
    } 
    elseif(($generateBookingDat >= ($season->winter_open)->format('Y-m-d')) && ($generateBookingDat < ($season->winter_close)->format('Y-m-d'))) 
    {
        print_r($generateBookingDat. ' booked on winter season ');
    }
    else 
    {
        print_r($generateBookingDat. ' Sorry not a season time ');
    }
}

// 2019-09-17 booked on summer season
// 2019-09-18 booked on summer season
// 2019-09-19 booked on summer season
// 2019-09-20 Sorry not a season time
// 2019-09-21 Sorry not a season time
```

Comment: @brtrnd, Thank you so much. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you need to improve table structure then you will handle these type of situations. Your table look like this:-

```
 id  season_type open_date  close_date    hotel  year
 1    winter    2018-05-01   2018-09-20     1     2018
 2    summer    2019-05-01   2019-09-20     1     2019
 3    summer    2018-05-01   2018-09-20     2     2018
 4    summer    2019-05-01   2019-09-20     2     2019
 if you want to save year you can save
```

After that same functionality you can do:-

```
 $seasons = Season::where('hotel',1)->get();
 Example 1:-
 $dateBegin  = 2019-09-17; 
 $dateEnd    = 2019-09-22;
 Example 2:-
 $dateBegin  = 2019-09-17;
 $dateEnd    = 2019-09-19;

foreach($seasons as $key=> $season){
    if($season->open_date >=  $dateBegin && $season->close_date <= $dateEnd){
        print_r('booked on .'$season->season_type'. season '); //save this in one array variable
    }else{
         print_r(Sorry not a season time');
    }
}
```

If you really use your table structure you will face many issues in future. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But at present condition I can't update tables structure.